# Executor accepting thread as input

Tags: java, concurrency

I recently started exploring Java Executor framework. All executors are designed to accept Runnable or Callable. Why executors does not accept Thread as an input?

Comment: Executors create threads for you. They accept what to run in the threads they create.

Comment: Why do you think it should accept a thread?

Comment: Reason is they create thread. If they have to create a thread they why not accept a thread as parameter.

Comment: What would they do with a thread that is already created? They would have no way of _executing_ tasks with it. If you need Executor to use threads created by your code, you should pass a thread _factory_ to the Executor's constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When talking about concurrency, it is **very important** to always distinguish between *threads* and *tasks*.

- A *task* is just a piece of work that should be done - often represented as `Runnable` (or `Callable` in case a task produces a result).
- A *thread* is a mechanism that enables *tasks* to be executed in parallel.

An `Executor` or `ExecutorService` is a facility that is able to execute *tasks*. Depending on the implementation, this executor may be able to execute multiple *tasks* in parallel - usually by using *threads* internally.

So if you are using an `Executor` or `ExecutorService`, you hand over *tasks*, hence `Runnable`s for execution and let the executor manage its *threads* for you.

*Note: As `java.lang.Thread` implements `Runnable`, it is possible to instantiate a `Thread` and pass it to `execute(...)`. That's a very bad thing as the executor will just invoke the `run()` method of the thread as if it were a task, and does not start the thread. It is not thought to be used this way - if you see this somewhere: It's wrong!*

Answer (score 0):

Well Java `Thread` class implements `Runnable` interface, thus technically it's possible to supply the Thread to the executor. However it will not start as a new thread, just its `run()` method will be called from one of the executor own threads.

Answer (score 0):

That is a great question

When you think of The Executor framework think of a line at your favorite fast food restaurant, you have sometimes maybe 4 cashiers taking orders an of course that long line.

- The long of line of people are the tasks that will be in the queue of the executor. Each carries what is called a Task (Runnable or Callable) in our example they are people that want to order their meal.
- The friendly cashiers are there to execute that order, when someone is in line and not talking to the cashier they are just waiting, however when you get a cashier, He or She is now working on your order.

When dealing with the Executor framework it helps having a mental model of a queue and bunch of servers (Threads). Now To complicate things just a bit, the executor service allows you to pass a [Threadfactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) This abstraction forces the framework to obey whatever rules you want when the thread pool need to create *new* cashiers (maybe the line is getting longer and many people are leaving the restaurant or angry). An example of why you want to do that, is maybe you want to name your threads in that pool something specific.

I hope that helps.